# Why do arrays do not accept input greater than their length?

Tags: java, arrays

I have noticed when inputting an integer into an array that if the integer is larger than the arrays length it will throw an out of bounds exception. Why is this? Why can the array not accept any integer value? How can I correct this when I need to store integers larger than an arrays length.

Thank you!

Here is the code. When I enter an integer greater than 5 I get an out of bounds exception. If I enter integers less than 5 the code works perfectly.

```
    public class NumOfOccur
{
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int[] cards = new int[5];
    static int[] numOccurence = new int[5];
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter five values: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Card " + (i + 1) + " : ");
            cards[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        containsPair(cards);
    }

    public static boolean containsPair(int hand[])
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < hand.length; i++)
            numOccurence[hand[i]]++;

        for (int i = 1; i < numOccurence.length; i++)
        {
            if (numOccurence[i] > 0)
                System.out.println("The number " + i + " occurs " + numOccurence[i] + " times.");
        }

        return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: This is just strictly not true. Post some code that you think demonstrates the problem so we can see what's actually going on. You only get `OutOfBoundsException` if you try to access an element beyond the array's length, not if the element itself is a larger number than `array.length`.

Comment: That's not correct. It sounds like you're passing the integer as the array index argument (for example, `myArray[myInt]`), instead of the value to assign to the index (`myArray[0] = myInt`).

Comment: are you sure you are not doing something like int[] i = new int[45]; i[50000] ..etc?

Answer (score 2):

What you are suggesting here is wrong.  An array of integers can hold any integer.  When you are storing an integer into an array (or any value for that matter) you have to make sure that the index you are inserting it into is valid.

For example

```
//perfectly valid
int[] foo = new int[1];
foo[0] = 500;
```

I suspect what you are doing is something like this.

```
//throws index out of bounds exception
int[] foo = new int[1];
foo[500] = 500;
```

Note the difference here.  the number inside the [] on the left side of the assignment operator indicate the index you are working with.

Based on your now posted code, your problem is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < hand.length; i++)
            numOccurence[hand[i]]++;
```

To briefly explain what is going on.

1) you first initialize numOccurence to a length of 5 integers.
2) You are putting user input into the cards[] then you pass the cards array into into the function containsPair()
3) If the user enters a number greater than 5, lets say 7 the operation `hands[i]` would be 7.  This would be the same as `numOccurence[7]` which is out of bounds

Answer (score 1):

Without any code, I'm assuming you're just misunderstanding what you're doing with your array. You just have to make sure you're accessing a valid index. There's no restriction on what integer you can store in an integer array.

```
// Make an array of length ten
int[] myIntArray = new int[10];
System.out.println(myIntArray.length);

// Set the first value in the array to 99: perfectly legal
myIntArray[0] = 99;
System.out.println(myIntArray[0]);

// The following line throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
myIntArray[99] = 100; // The last index in the array is only 9, not 99!
System.out.println(myIntArray[99]); // This line would also crash, for the same reason
```

Answer (score 1):

Having seen your code, I think the issue is with this:

First, your `numOccurence` array always has a length of 5, but in the line

```
numOccurence[hand[i]]++;
```

You will get the `OutOfBoundsException` if `hand[i]` is 5 or greater (meaning you typed in a value of 5 or greater).

To fix this you should either:

1. Put restrictions on what card values the user can enter
2. Make that line `numOccurence[i]++` if you mean to keep track of the number of times each *card position* was drawn
3. Make `numOccurence` a longer array so it can store the number of times each possible card (e.g. 1 to 13 for Ace to King) has occured.

Comment: 4. Make `numOccurence` a `Map<Integer,Integer>`, 6. Make `numOccurence` `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight If you made `numOccurence` an `ArrayList<Integer>` then do you suggest that you deliberately pad the list with `0` values until you get to the hypothetical gigantic card number that has just occurred?

Answer (score 0):

I'm definitely sure the question is wrong. You're saying this is not possible

```
int[] anArray = new int[10];
anArray[5] = 20;
```

Which is obviously not true.

If that's what you're saying, post your code, because you have a bug.

If you want to make your array larger or something, you should consider using an ArrayList or something similar. Post your code so we can help you.